# How to avoid receiving warning message from a mount system

Tags: mount, administration, messaging, broadcast

I asked similar question in [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1034303/linux-how-to-not-receive-broadcast-warning-message-about-low-disk), no satisfying answer. Re-post here with some update.

I mount a remote host to my system during debug because the source code is on that host, but after I do the mount, I keep receiving the warning message:

```
Broadcast message from root@<the remote host> (Mon Feb  1 10:59:03 2016):

Disk partition /src_host has only 5% free
```

/src_host is the mount point at my host.

It is very disruptive as it shows up every 2 minutes.

I tried "mesg n" command, but it does not help. My suspicion is I log in my host as "root" and the warning message is sent from "root" also.

I cannot change the remote host, only change the local host.

The only thing I can think of is, create a new user at the local host and log in as that user. Not done that before. Like to avoid the hassle if possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is sshfs an option?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. add space or remove files from the mount in the hopes of getting it under whatever threshold this wall process is using.
2. Try to block the rpc traffic. Run `rpcinfo | grep walld`. Then run `rpcinfo -d <the number from the first column> 1`. This will remove walld from the list of listening rpc services on your host.

Example:

```
$ rpcinfo | grep walld
100008  1         ticlts,udp                       walld
$ rpcinfo -d 100008 1
```

Comment: I get the error:  

rpcinfo: can't contact rpcbind: RPC: Remote system error - No such file or directory

Comment: to confirm; you're using NFS to mount the share? The error you got makes it sound like rpcbind is not running, which I think NFS would require.